# css large margin but borders overlap

Tags: css

The navigation moves down to the next line so they they stay in the browser, and that is when the borders overlap. How can I make it so that the borders have space in-between them vertically? Horizontally, the margin works like normal, adding space between the elements as the pixels increase, but not vertically.

```css
.nav:link {
     color: #118794;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 10px;
     padding: 4px;
     border-width: 4px;
     border-style: ridge;
}
.nav:visited {
     color: #0BB545;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 10px;
     padding: 4px;
     border-width: 4px;
     border-style: groove;
}
.nav:hover {
     color: #0BB545;
     text-decoration: underline;
     border-style: groove;}    
     border-style: groove;
 }
```

```html
      <nav class="navbar">
       <a class="nav" id="top" href="index.html">Home</a>
       <!--**Create Drop Down for People-->
       <a class="nav" href="family/utahfamily.html">My Family</a>
       <a class="nav" href="friends/utahfriends.html">Friends</a>
       <!--**Create Drop Down for places-->
       <a class="nav" href="hiking/utahhiking.html">Hiking</a>
       <a class="nav" href="recreation/utahrecreation.html">Recreation</a>
       <a class="nav" href="restaurants/utahrestaurants.html">Restaurants</a>
       <!--**Create Drop Down for Adventures-->
       <a class="nav" href="mountainadventure/utahmountains.html">Mountains Adventure</a>
       <a class="nav" href="ranchadventure/utahranch.html">Ranch Adventure</a>
       <a class="nav" href="tuningadventure/utahtuning.html">Piano Tuning Adventure</a>
       <a class="nav" href="/otherthings/stufftodo.html">Other Things to Do</a>
       <!--contact-->
       <a class="nav" href="contact/contact.html">Contact</a>
      </nav>
      
      <!--end  nav-->
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide some minimal HTML so we have an example (see [MCVE]). Note also there is a html/css/js tool you can use to make your code runnable inline.

Comment: Ok. I added the Html. Sorry, I'm new. Also, I can't add a photo until I have 10 points, otherwise I would include one.

Comment: That's fine, much better. Note you have a duplication in your CSS, though likely unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the behavior - the CSS is treating everything as inline (default), and this is how it looks like with borders/margins/paddings since the margin is only on the links. One solution as to use `inline-block` (might want to get rid of margins now):

```css
.nav:link {
     color: #118794;
     text-decoration: none;
      display:inline-block;
     margin: 10px;
     padding: 4px;
     border-width: 4px;
     border-style: ridge;
}
.nav:visited {
     color: #0BB545;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 10px;
     padding: 4px;
     border-width: 4px;
     border-style: groove;
}
.nav:hover {
     color: #0BB545;
     text-decoration: underline;
     border-style: groove;
 }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
       <a class="nav" id="top" href="index.html">Home</a>
       <!--**Create Drop Down for People-->
       <a class="nav" href="family/utahfamily.html">My Family</a>
       <a class="nav" href="friends/utahfriends.html">Friends</a>
       <!--**Create Drop Down for places-->
       <a class="nav" href="hiking/utahhiking.html">Hiking</a>
       <a class="nav" href="recreation/utahrecreation.html">Recreation</a>
       <a class="nav" href="restaurants/utahrestaurants.html">Restaurants</a>
       <!--**Create Drop Down for Adventures-->
       <a class="nav" href="mountainadventure/utahmountains.html">Mountains Adventure</a>
       <a class="nav" href="ranchadventure/utahranch.html">Ranch Adventure</a>
       <a class="nav" href="tuningadventure/utahtuning.html">Piano Tuning Adventure</a>
       <a class="nav" href="/otherthings/stufftodo.html">Other Things to Do</a>
       <!--contact-->
       <a class="nav" href="contact/contact.html">Contact</a>
      </nav>
      
      <!--end  nav-->
```